# OS X : How to pass CPCL command through USB to Zebra printer?

Tags: macos, zebra-printers, utility

I am working on a mac app. I have studied a lot but didn't find any help. I want to send CPCL command via USB to printer for printer setup utility (Like change current IP assigned to that printer)

These are the CPCL commands that i want to give to printer via USB :

`! U1 setvar "ip.dhcp.enable" "off"`

`! U1 setvar "ip.addr" "192.168.1.123”`

`! U1 setvar "ip.netmask" "255.255.255.0"`

`! U1 setvar "ip.gateway" "192.168.1.2"`

`! U1 setvar "device.friendly_name" "myprinter"`

`! U1 setvar "wlan.essid" "mywifi"`

`! U1 do "device.reset" ""`